# DateTime month format for en-US

Tags: c#

I am parsing some dates to be the MMM-dd-yyyy format, but for some reason my month names are coming out in non-standard english names.

May is Mai, October is Okt, March is Mrz , December Dez , why are these not May, Oct, Mar and Dec?

Where am I going wrong?

```
DateTime projectStartDay = DateTime.Parse("1/1/2017",CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US"));
DateTime projectEndDay = DateTime.Parse("12/1/2017",CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US"));

Console.WriteLine(projectStartDay.ToString("MMM-dd-yyyy"));
Console.WriteLine(projectEndDay.ToString("MMM-dd-yyyy"));
```

I get the following:

> Jan-01-2017
>   Dez-01-2017 ← I would like that to be Dec-01-2017

Comment: The culture you use to parse the text to `DateTime` values has absolutely no impact on the culture used to convert those `DateTime` values to text when you output them.  If you want to use US culture when converting your `DateTime` values to text, which is what `ToString` is doing, then you have to specify US culture there, not before.

Comment: this "non-standard english names" look like German - perhaps that's the culture set for the application :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify the culture when you print it out.

```
  // Creates a CultureInfo for en-US.
  CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("en-US");
  string format = "MMM-dd-yyyy";

  Console.WriteLine(projectStartDay.ToString(format, ci));
  Console.WriteLine(projectEndDay.ToString(format, ci));
```